# Passing data from ViewController to UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

I have on FirstViewController an array with float value.
I need to pass to my View this array when the user clicks on a button.
This button will call the View and draw the points informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
In your FirstViewController.h write

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
extern NSArray *yourArray;
```

And in your FirstViewController.m write

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController ()
@end
NSArray *yourArray;
```

Now you'll have to import the whole FirstViewController in your "MyView"-Class.
Simply
    #import "FirstViewController.h"
in MyView.m. After doing so, "yourArray" will be available in MyView.

Or, **2.**, you could write something like this into MyView.h:

```
- (void)drawRect(NSArray *)yourArray;
```

and in your FirstViewController.m, simply pass the data: (don't forget to #include MyView.h)

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc]init];
[myView drawRect:yourArray]; //You'll have to pass "yourArray", to the function in MyView, which is going to be called
```

Or, **3.**, if you're using storyboard, you could

```
- (IBAction)pushedButton(UIButton *)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushButton" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushButton"] {
MyView *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
destinationViewController.yourArray = yourArray; // you'll have to define yourArray in the .h File
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I lost 2 days trying to use this array on MyView. The first answer worked fine.